# Using MongoDB relationally

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I've been looking into MongoDB and how it compares to conventional SQL databases. I'm trying to understand to what degree it makes sense to incorporate cross-document/object referencing before switching over to an RDBMS altogether. I understand many-to-many relationships pretty much necessitate it (given a concern of duplication and consistency), as well as certain scenarios with multiple one-to-many relationships — such as the following [example from the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)...

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
}
```

... requiring another one-to-many relationship between say, `property_developer` (with its own required set of properties) and the addresses.

Based on my budding knowledge of MongoDB, I'd originally have guessed a requirement for cross-referencing would default SQL as the no-brainer, but I'm discovering that it seems to be an acceptable design pattern in what I (mistakenly?) understood to be a non-relational database. So for someone considering NoSQL/MongoDB, is there a general rule of thumb by which one can determine whether their needs are instead better suited to a conventional RDBMS?

Comment: Relations is the only one thing to consider. Other things are consistency, transactions, scalability. Take a look at https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql in general, and https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 in terms of docrefs vs embeded docs.

Comment: Understood, but is there no degree of cross-referencing alone beyond which sticking with NoSQL is rendered flat-out impractical?

Comment: I believe the document behind the first link has some examples where relational db is more suitable. Apart from that it would worth mentioning that with MongoDB you are basically limited to built-in functions of aggregation framework. The more flexible map-reduce is not recommended for operational queries. To put it simple, if you don't know why you need mongodb, you probably don't need it.

Comment: Difficult to say, but its probably difficult if your whole data model relies on multiple joins across multiple pieces of data. Otherwise you can create almost any relationship through embedding/normalization

Comment: How about this blog https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 (and then part 2 and part 3)

Comment: @AlexBlex Can't seem to find anything on that. Could you specify where?

Comment: right after words "there are use cases for which a relational database like MySQL would be better suited"

Comment: @AlexBlex Sorry, thought you meant the link in my Question. Yeah, I'd previously checked that out, but "complex, multi-row transactions" is a little vague for me. I guess a laid out concrete example is something I'm looking for.

Comment: A concrete example would apply to concrete circumstances. One may consider 5 cross-references is way to complex, while another is happy to handle 500. The phrase should be read as 'the more references/transactions you require, there more obvious sql advantages'. It's up to you where to draw the line.

Comment: So maybe I'm looking for a concrete circumstance. I just figured there must be a ballpark number of normalized relationships at which transactional performance yields to an RDBMS of the same data requirements.